# Does IOS Dictation Database Contain “UGH”

Tags: ios, voice-dictation

I recently had someone reply to me over text and they claim “speech” to text wrote “ugh” instead of “huh”. It was part of a text that offended me by how it was written and I believe they intentionally wrote “ugh”, even though they claim otherwise. This person uses “ugh” quite often to portray or describe displeasure.

I’ve tried multiple times to get speech to text to produce “ugh” and I don’t think its in IOS natural database to do so.

I know you can manually make IOS learn words, but it’s not in their accessibility database as an entry.

Comment: If that person uses a word frequently, it will likely be in their database… which still proves nothing. I'd stop worrying about it.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh / huh / aah is easily produced by dictation from similar sounds even in an exceptionally quiet environment with clear diction. (i.e. Works on iPad and Apple Watch and iPhone for me.)

How Apple engineered the system is probably a lot more complicated than you’ve written, but there’s no technical gotcha I can see that would reinforce any mistrust of said person.

In my experience, Siri is extremely flexible with accents and has to juggle many inputs / guess contextually what a sound actually means to produce text that in the end looks identical to a very intentionally typed statement.

For decades to come I think we all will continue to be part of experiments to [help Apple wreck a nice beach](http://www.i2osig.org/speech.html).